Зачем в MySQL при удалении поля в таблице используют COLUMN?
У меня есть таблица в phpMyAdmin, когда я хочу удалить из нее столбец, я использую:
ALTER TABLE pepole DROP bio;

Но когда я смотрю примеры из интернета, вижу что люди используют следущее:
ALTER TABLE pepole DROP COLUMN bio; 

Я понимаю что COLUMN - это столбец, но обязательно ли его использовать, если у меня и так все работает?

Судя по документации, это необязательный параметр DROP [COLUMN] col_name, наверное люди используют его для большей понятности. Можно использовать, можно нет.

pepole??.. DROP без аргумента по умолчанию просто принимает COLUMN.. но, разве удалять можно только столбец? Есть еще индексы например...

ALTER TABLE DROP без указания конкретного объекта может удалять как поле, так и индекс. При отсутствии опционального ключевого слова и наличии объектов обоих типов с таким именем - фактически удаляется поле, а не индекс, но это не документировано (или я не нашёл).
Но это надо знать и помнить. Использование опционального ключевого слова полностью снимает неоднозначность того, что вы собственно удаляете.
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  column1 INT,
  column2 INT,
  column3 INT,
  KEY column1 (column1),
  KEY column2 (column2),
  KEY column3 (column3)
);
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;




Table
Create Table




test
CREATE TABLE `test` (  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,  `column1` int DEFAULT NULL,  `column2` int DEFAULT NULL,  `column3` int DEFAULT NULL,  KEY `column1` (`column1`),  KEY `column2` (`column2`),  KEY `column3` (`column3`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci



-- Явно удаляем COLUMN, удаляется и соответствующий индекс
ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN column1;
-- Явно удаляем индекс, поле не удаляется
ALTER TABLE test DROP INDEX column2;
-- Не указываем, что удалять, удаляются и поле, и индекс
ALTER TABLE test DROP column3;

SHOW CREATE TABLE test;




Table
Create Table




test
CREATE TABLE `test` (  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,  `column2` int DEFAULT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci



fiddle
Относитесь к использованию опциональных ключевых слов как к неявному документированию.

Не плохо, ответил пока я печатал комментарий) плюсик

«это не документировано» — в документации DROP [COLUMN] завёрнуто в квадратные скобки, а DROP {KEY | INDEX} — в фигурные; думаю, это можно считать задокументированием. Если название поля и название индекса не совпадают, DROP column3key ответит Can't DROP COLUMN `column3key`; check that it exists — то есть оно однозначно пытается удалять именно поле

@andreymal речь не о том, что ключевое слово опционально. Речь о том, что при наличии одноимённых поля и индекса при выполнении ALTER TABLE DROP без указания удаляемого объекта удаляется именно поле, а не индекс. Вот этот приоритет поля перед индексом нигде и не описан.

@Akina как я уже отметил в предыдущем комментарии — описан различающимися скобочками

Тут вещают про то, что DROP index_name не существует в природе. Удаление индекса может происходить только при использовании полной команды. В ответе описан кейс, когда индекс построен на одноименном столбце, поэтому если  грохнуть столбец, грохнется и индекс на него ссылающийся. Если бы не было столбца, команда выдала бы ошибку.

что видимо можно проверить на create table x (c1 int, index c2 (c1)); alter table x drop c2;

@teran Так как раз это у меня в ответе и демонстрируется. В принципе насчёт скобочек Андрей совершенно прав - в DROP COLUMN ключевое слово COLUMN опционально (скобки квадратные), а вот в DROP INDEX - обязательно, но имеет альтернативные написания (скобки фигурные).

ALTER TABLE pepole DROP bio;

это сокращенная форма запроса, они оба выполняют одинаковое действие и можно пользовать и первым запросом и вторым
